# Unable to flag upvoted comments

Tags: feature-request, comments, flags

Once you have upvoted a comment, it is no longer possible to flag it.

If you have upvoted a comment in the past, it's likely not going to be "spam" or "offensive", however, you may later want to mark a comment as "obsolete".

Comment: Related on MSO: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104184/allow-flagging-a-comment-after-upvoting-it